# How can I get rid of "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider"

Tags: c#

I am trying to use .NET's connectivity with databases, using a non-standard DB (Aspen's SQLPlus).

My code, for now, is very simple:

```
using System.Data.Common;
static class Module1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().Rows(0)(2));
    }
}
```

With my app.config looking like:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspenTech SQLPlus Data Provider" invariant="AspenTech.SQLplus.DataProvider" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLplus" type="AspenTech.SQLplus.DataProvider.SQLplusProviderFactory, AspenTech.SQLplus.DataProvider, Version=12.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79727a7ee33da274"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

However, I get a runtime error:

`Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider`.

I am aware that there is a bunchload of quasi-duplicates, **I have read them all**.

In particular, I have made sure that the `AspenTech.SQLplus.DataProvider.dll` is copied to the bin folder.

I have read all that the Internet has to say about this, but have not found anything...

Comment: Usually, assembly binding logging is your friend here. If any attempt is made to load the assembly at all, it will tell you why it didn't work. If the binding isn't logged, you know it's some configuration issue preventing the load from happening at all.

Comment: My money is on the version number or public token not matching that of the assembly.

Comment: Try to load the assembly with Assembly.Load(longName) - thus you can check if you have the token/version correct or logging for binding failures (just type "Fusion" in the start menu)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have tried with Assembly.Load, and it works fine. I'll try to use assembly binding logging, but I am not admin of my PC, so it's bureaucraty time, yay!